# Got socket error trying to find package at https://pub.dev

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I need to get many packages while developing mob app using flutter. I am beginner and I am getting following error.(I have attached image)
[Socket error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoV3q.png)

How can resolve this issue?

I have closed command prompt and opened again.
I have restarted my router (internet working fine though)

Comment: Could you check whether this site is opening in your network or not? https://pub.dev/packages/intro_slider/